# Simplest quick sort using one 19-line function

Tags: java, recursion, sorting, quick-sort

This will later be be posted on my website to explain quick sort so I would like how I could improve the readability and simplicity of this demo class. I do not like my use of the stack (meaning this recursion cannot process a list with millions of values).

How could I reduce the stack impact? I think the best way would be not to use as many `ArrayList` instances. However, I don't know how else because I cannot use lists like `int[] list` because I do not know their size and surely if I just make it too big the loops will be bigger and take longer.

Here is the class in question:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSort {

    static Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int listsize = 100000, range = 100000;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<listsize; i++)
            list.add(r.nextInt(range));
        sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> sort(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        if (list.size() <= 1) 
            return list;
        int rotationplacement = r.nextInt(list.size());
        int rotation = list.get(rotationplacement);
        list.remove(rotationplacement);
        ArrayList<Integer> lower = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> higher = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int num : list)
            if (num <= rotation)
                lower.add(num);
            else
                higher.add(num);
        sort(lower);
        sort(higher);

        list.clear();
        list.addAll(lower);
        list.add(rotation);
        list.addAll(higher);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: sidenote: instantiate arraylists as ``List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: BTW, recursion here won't be a problem. Each 3 digits of values adds 10 to the stack depth since the depth is log(*n*). A billion values will require only 30 stack frames at the most.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating new `List`s, your method could sort the list in place. The method you call recursively could take the list and index values; the methods would look something like this:

```
/**
 * sorts the {@code list} in place
 */
public static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    sort(list, 0, list.size());
}

/**
 * Sorts the {@code list} from {@code fromIndex} to {@code toIndex} - 1.
 */
private static void sort(List<Integer> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {

    if (fromIndex == toIndex - 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        // find the pivot, Collections.swap elements, etc...
        // recursively call self.
    }

}
```

Sorting the list in place reduces the amount of memory on the stack.

Also, to make the code more generic, perhaps you could sort lists of `Comparable` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: I don't think I see how that would improve the stack, for the first function why should I sort a copy of the list? and surely the extra two params for the second are redundant because it will always sort from 0 to list.size(), otherwise its sending a too big list. I think you mean to put the lists in a non-recurring function? Please could you explain more on what you meant by "sort the list in place" (in place?). Thanks for introducing me to comparable though.

Comment: @LeeAllan I was incorrectly assuming your original function returned a new list and left the original unmodified. Since that is not true, I would recommend copying the Collections.sort API which returns `void`.

Comment: @LeeAllan, As far as sorting the list in place, I will add a bit more code to try and clarify

Comment: @LeeAllan - Passing the list to each successive call only adds a *reference* to the stack. The list values remain in the heap and don't get copied from call-to-call. Sorting in-place is the right way to go for an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Minor note: You may as well change the parameter to the second method to `ArrayList` since the public API specifies this already.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you want me to do, to pass the same beginning list recursively so the stack uses a pointer, however I don't see how it's possible without creating a lower and higher list and surely they're the culprit of the memory. Can someone please show me exactly what "sort in place" means with some code?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the sorting in place already mentioned by @kuporific, you should

- provide comments in your code about assumptions, at least on the parameters 
  of `sort()`
- you should very clearly mark this as example code and what (standard) 
  functions should be used in real sorting
- you should include in this code an appropriate reference to Sir Tony Hoare.

All that could be done in the context of a website, but cut-and-pasted code has a life of its own, so get these comments **in** the class.